# Sql Server execution plan, cost of non-clustered index scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Is it a bad symptom that non-clustered index scan cost is 53% ?

Comment: Looks like this is better suited to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well it's better than a table scan I guess. Can you post the tables and the query? The query and/or index could may well be more efficiently written.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your query. The total query always costs 100%. So if you have a query like

```
SELECT Name from Customers WHERE ID = 3
```

than the index scan or seek may even cost 100%. That doesn't mean it's a bad thing. If you want a clear answer about you're query then you should at least post the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not use non-clustered index with key/bookmark lookup in the case if it expects iterator to return more than a few % of the total rows from the table.

Comment: [Looks like you just copied that phrase from here](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/29/when-sql-server-uses-non-clustered-indexes/). How does that answer the question anyway? In your view is 53% a bad sympton?

Comment: Yes it is. And need to check all the scenario in which it gets effected.